# Burn .exe 'output format' is 'opaque'?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, burn

*Disclaimer: I'm fairly new to burn...*

The .exe files created by WiX Burn bundles are some type of self extracting zip archives, however they seem fairly opaque in structure and I cant find any documentation on them.  For example in 7zip a Burn .exe looks like this:

[image: burn screenshot]

Whereas a traditional .vdproj bundle (and other bootstrappers I have seen) include the bundled files verbatum in a traditional file system.

**QUESTIONS:**

1. Is the output format documented anywhere?
2. Is there any way to
   recover the contents without installing? **EDIT** it seems dark.exe can do this, so *2a. is there anything outside the WiX toolkit...*
3. Is there any way to
   change the output format?

Thank you.

**NB** *The reason I ask is that there are many circumstances (corporate IT departments say) where people extract the .msi files out of traditional bootstrappers to wrap into their own logic / examine the bootstrapper contents as part of an approval process.*

Comment: Re 2a: Dark is as easy to download, unzip, and run as 7-zip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, the format for an attached container is undocumented (intentionally, so we can change it later). Today, in WiX v3.10, it's a .cab file attached to the .exe.
2. (a) It's possible but there are no such tools today (that I know of) other than Dark.exe.
3. No, not today. Obviously, you could use external payloads so they're not attached to the .exe.